# My MATLAB program is not executing the IF STATEMENT. I'm calculating the values of the left and right sides of the equation for x=200

Tags: matlab, trigonometry

I want to print the statement "They are equal" if the left side equation is equal to the right side equation for x=200. This is the equation.
[image: (sin(x) + cos(x))^2=1+2*(sin(x)*cos(x))]

But when my program calculates the right side and left side equation, it does not execute the if statement even though the two sides are equal for x=200.
This is my program:

```
clear, clc

x = 200;
left_side = (sin(x) + cos(x))^2;
right_side = 1+2*(sin(x)*cos(x));

if right_side == left_side
    disp('they are equal')
end
```

I have tried debugging the program step by step and checked the values in memory after each step and nothing seems to be wrong.

[image: values in memory]

But the if statement still does not execute. Is there anything I am missing?
Thank you for your help.

Comment: Try removing the `;`'s you don't need them in Python and they can cause unexpected results.

Comment: That's because they are not equal, just very close to each other. Try evaluating `left_side - right_side`, you'll notice it's not zero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're running into is a floating point rounding error. Here what you want to do is compare if the numbers are equal within a certain tolerance instead of directly equal; for example to 10 decimal places. Doing this should fix the code:

```
clear, clc

x = 200;

left_side = (sin(x) + cos(x))^2;
right_side = 1+2*(sin(x)*cos(x));
tolerence = 1e-10;
if abs(left_side - right_side) < tolerance
    disp('they are equal')
end
```

Also, since this was tagged with Python as well I thought I should throw in that as of Python3.5 the math module includes [math.isclose()](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.5.html#pep-485-a-function-for-testing-approximate-equality) in case others come across this post.